# How to authorize POST form upload in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I want to create a simple form where user enters some string (key that authorizes them to upload a file) and the file they want to upload (no size limit, can be even 10GB or more).

The problem I have is that I don't know how to verify the code BEFORE accepting the file.

So far I have this code that disallows any upload even with a valid code since the uploaded file seems to be always the first form element to be checked.
(when I reversed the order of elements in the form this code didn't handle the request at all)

```
            var isAuth = false
            multipart.forEachPart { part ->
                when (part) {
                    is PartData.FormItem -> {
                        val name = part.name
                        if(name != null && name == "key")
                            isAuth = isKeyValid(part.value)
                    }
                    is PartData.FileItem -> {
                        if(!isAuth) {
                            call.respond("Request not authorized")
                            call.response.status(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                            part.dispose
                            return@forEachPart
                        }
                        if(part.originalFileName.isNullOrEmpty() || part.originalFileName!!.isBlank()) {
                            call.respond("Illegal filename")
                            call.response.status(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                            return@forEachPart
                        }
                        val targetDir = File(uploadDir.path + File.separator + randomId)
                        targetDir.mkdir()
                        val targetFile = File(targetDir.path + File.separator + part.originalFileName)
                        targetFile.createNewFile()
                        sb.append(randomId)
                        sb.append("/")
                        sb.append(part.originalFileName)
                        sb.append("\n")
                        part.streamProvider().use { input -> targetFile.outputStream().buffered().use { output -> input.copyToSuspend(output) } }
                    }
                }
                part.dispose
            }
```

HTML form I'm using:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="text" name="key">

    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should pass authorization data in HTTP headers rather than in the body

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Normally I would use curl and append `?key=mykey` to the URL, but I don't know if it's possible to send half POST half GET request with html form (judging by the search results in google it's not possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add Authentication feature

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version"
```

2. Install the feature

```
install(Authentication) { //set type of authenction here }
```

1. Wrap your call in `authenticate {}` block

```
authenticate("auth") {
  post(FORM) {
  }
}
```

More Info: [Ktor Authentication](https://ktor.io/servers/features/authentication.html)